# Ranorex scripting; how do I send commands to the browser?

Tags: console, ranorex

Ranorex scripting; how do I send commands to the browser?
I would like to send a command string to the browser, i.e. instead of using the browser developer tools console input

Comment: Please show a sample of code you have tried so far

Comment: The Ranorex library can be used as an extension to .Net so presumably this is possible, but I'm wondering if you are making this harder than it needs to be. What exactly are you trying to do that you need to do this?

Comment: Just trying to send a Jquery string to the browser to remove large activity, e.g. user activity net traffic on a site loaded with analytics

Comment: I think what you are looking for here is the execute script command on the webDocument class.  It allows you to run a javascript function.  Sorry I don't know a whole lot about it, but here is the link to get you started using it.

http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/web-testing/samples.html#c1986

Answer (score 1):

I agree with theDarse. Take a look at the following website:
http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/web-testing/samples.html#c1986
The following code should work.

```
webDocument.ExecuteScript("history.back();");
```